# Ansible Ad-Hoc find file with pattern

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run an adhoc `find` command in ansible to look for `myFile.txt` but it's giving me an `unknown hosts` error. What am I doing wrong?

`ansible all -m file -a patterns="myFile.txt" paths="/home/user/Documents"`

Answer (score 2):

Combine all arguments into one parameter. Note the single quotes. If you use double quotes, you must escape them

`ansible all -m find -a "patterns='myFile.txt' paths='/home/user/Documents'"`

or

`ansible all -m find -a "patterns=\"myFile.txt\" paths=\"/home/user/Documents\"`

Comment: There's no need to use quotes inside the expression: `ansible all -m find -a "patterns=myFile.txt paths=/home/user/Documents"` is perfectly ok; even with wildcards `ansible all -m find -a "patterns=my*.txt paths=/home/user/Documents"`.